# Windows Server 2008, NodeJS, Socket.IO issue with number of clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io, windows-server-2008-r2

I’ve written a Socket.IO Chat server in NodeJS and running on Windows Server 2008. When doing load testing I’m only able to get to about 4.000 connections before I’m getting ’connection time out’.

https://github.com/fbacker/NodeChat-SocketIO/blob/master/app.js

Is there something I’m missing? Are there some custom settings that’s needed to done on the server that’s outside of the configuration in code?

The chat is clustered over CPU;s and using Redis. It will run on 4 servers so after reading a lot of the technique I wasn’t worried. But now I’m afraid the system will crash on a big game night where’s we think 20.000 people will run the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default windows allows to use only ports from 1000 up to 5000 to be used for connection handling.

You can increase this limit.
Check this out http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html